# Jquery UI Drag and drop - How to drop dragged content into selected target(child) of parent elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have two divs source(containing dragging an element) and target(space for dropping dragged content). I have set and append the row with four columns into the target div to be droppable. you can find  a sample code in        http://jsfiddle.net/yLhvxv0d/5/ . all are working  in view of dragging and dropping. But What  my problem is "when i dragged a content into the child of target div , the dragged content was appending to the entire tree which is from parent to selected child target", so please help me

1) how to drop the content into the selected child, without dropping into their parent elements

Find below my  code:

```
<div>
 <p class="draggable" name="name">Name</p>
 <p class="draggable" name="Gender">Gender</p>
 <p class="draggable" name="Address">Address</p>
</div>
<div class="droppable mytable">
<div class="droppable row mytable">
<div class="droppable col-sm-3 mytable">
  </div>
<div class="droppable col-sm-3 mytable">
</div>
<div class="droppable col-sm-3 mytable">
</div>
<div class="droppable col-sm-3 mytable">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(".draggable").draggable({
  helper: "clone"
});

$('.droppable').droppable({
  accept: '.draggable',
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
</script>
```

find the executable code from [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLhvxv0d/5/)

Edited:

I want to drag and drop in both parent as well as child elements based on selection. those child elements are dynamically append to parent div based on user input. suppose for example user want to drag the element and drop into the parent div it has to drop in parent div, and as well as if user wants to drop the dragged element in child node it able to drop into child node only. I think you people understood my requirement. and this question is entirely different what you referenced question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop event fire 3 times. For the 2 parents and for one children (all have the class "draggable"). Add a class to the children, and check if the drop element have the correct class:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p class="draggable" name="name">Name</p>
  <p class="draggable" name="Gender">Gender</p>
  <p class="draggable" name="Address">Address</p>
</div>
<div class="droppable mytable">
  <div class="droppable row mytable">
    <div class="droppable col-sm-3 mytable children">

    </div>
    <div class="droppable col-sm-3 mytable children">

    </div>
    <div class="droppable col-sm-3 mytable children">

    </div>
    <div class="droppable col-sm-3 mytable children">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Drop Event:

```
 if ($(this).hasClass('children')) {
    $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($(this));
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yLhvxv0d/8/

Comment: see i want to drag and drop in both parent as well as child elements based on selection. those child elements are dynamically append to parent div based on user input. suppose for example user want to drag the element and drop into the parent div it has to drop in parent div, and as well as if user wants to drop the dragged element in child node it able to drop into child node only. I think you people understood my requirement. and this question is entirely different what you referenced question

Comment: The other answer is better of mine if you want drop on single container parents or children, this is the example : http://jsfiddle.net/yLhvxv0d/10/ is right ?

Comment: Thanks [Baro](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4031083/baro) ,Its works great.